# How crate apex class Salesforce

Tags: class, salesforce, apex, processbuilder, account

apex class should make next logic. when new Account is created, create new Task object with Subject "negotiations with {Account.Name}", link created Account with this Task

```
public with sharing class AccountProcessBuilder{
       @InvocableMethod
       public static void createTask() {
          Task newTask = new Task();
          newTask.Subject = "negotiations with" + {Account.Name}"
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Apex class, in Process Builder itself you can create a record on Task object with the required values.